# Postman : How to set test environnement?

Tags: rest, api, symfony, environment-variables, postman

I have a rest API with symfony and two local environments:

- dev (env.local)
- test (env.test.local)

My Behat tests run on the test environment with a dedicated database.

But when I call a resource with Postman, it always uses the `dev` environment (all new resources are created on the dev database).

I tried to create a new environment on Postman with all the variables and values of my `dev.test.local` (included the test database access).

[image]

[image]

[image]

But it doesn't work. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Do you select the test environment when running/wanting to get access for that data set? You might need to expand on the detail of the requests and also add additional images of the app when sending the requests (mask the sensitive info), a zoomed-in look at the environment details doesn't really explain the issue.

Comment: yes, the test env is selected and the request result is from the dev database.

Comment: How are you referencing those values in the request?

Comment: what do you mean by that ? I'm not referencing anything. I have to reenter the test variables again in the request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the different variables for each `environment` selected, you need to make references to the variable names in your requests using the `{{..}}` syntax.

I don't know what value you have for the `APP_DEV` variable but that would be used in the URL like this:

```
GET http://{{APP_DEV}}/api/users
```

The way to make these the most effective is to create the variables with the same name in the `environment` files and then make each value different under the different environment files.

For example:

```
GET http://{{DOMAIN}}/api/users
```

If you have a `DOMAIN` key in each environment but change the value of that variable. When you switch between the two environments, it's going to use the variable key but use a different value for `dev` and `test`.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/variables-and-environments/variables/

Comment: APP_ENV values are juste "dev" or "test", its not an url.

Comment: If you have no placeholders for the variables in the requests, it's not going to pick up any of the data from the environment selected. APP_DEV was _just_ an example, I don't know anything about any of the variables you're using.